# set parameters for built in function in apply,R

Tags: r, function, apply

Here is the original code,

```
 x <- apply(matrix, MARGIN = c(2,3),FUN = functionA)
```

where matrix has 3 dimensions and functionA is a one input one output function.

Now I want to add some more parameters in functionA, like below,

```
x <- apply(matrix,MARGIN = c(2,3), FUN = functionA(,extraParameters))
```

But now functionA will become a two input one output function, which doesn't work.

the only way I can think of is set functionA like below

```
functionA <- function(input,extraParameters = NULL){}
```

and set extraParameters by a global variable.

But in that way I will have too many global variables, '

Could anyone tell me is there simiple ways to solve the problem, like I just put

```
 x <- apply(matrix,MARGIN = c(2,3), FUN = functionA(,extraParameters))
```

Thank you.

Comment: Have a look at `?apply`, the help page of `apply`. There are examples of this.

Comment: You just need to add your extra parameters after `FUN = functionA`, separated by commas.

Comment: Thank you! i‘ve checked the examples!